# get selected value in datePicker and format it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

In the datePicker selected `20.04.2012`. I want to get this value, format it and store in a variable.
I uses this code:

```
var date = $("#scheduleDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd,MM,yyyy' }).val();
```

But result is `20.04.2012`.
Also, I tryed this code:

```
var dateTypeVar = $('#scheduleDate').datepicker('getDate');
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd-MM-yy', dateTypeVar);
```

Result is `Fri Apr 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0600`.

I want to get the following: `20, April, 2012`
How to format properly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### If you want to take the formatted value of input do this :

```
$("input").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd, mm, yy' });
```

later in your code when the date is set you could get it by

```
dateVariable = $("input").val();
```

#### If you want just to take a formatted value with datepicker you might want to use the utility

```
dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd, MM, yy', new Date("20 April 2012"));
```

I've updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drinchev/5bwjL/3/) for experimenting with this

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to format value IN datepicker. I want GET value from datePicker and FORMAT it and store in variable.

Comment: @drinchev, Hello, in my case when I'm intialize the datepicker value to a variable it's undefined, yet when I call alert to show datepicker value, nothing goes wrong.

Example when in date picker I choose 2016, the $("input").val() show 2016, but when I initialize it to variable year and call the year, it's undefined.

Answer (score 4):

```
var dateObject = $("#datePickerInput").datepicker('getDate');
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd MM, yy', dateObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jquery-dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat). It will solve your problem.

You need to include the jquery.dateFormat in your html file.

```
<script>
var date = $('#scheduleDate').val();
document.write($.format.date(date, "dd,MM,yyyy"));

var dateTypeVar = $('#scheduleDate').datepicker('getDate');
document.write($.format.date(dateTypeVar, "dd-MM-yy"));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I don't want to include new plugin for format date.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#scheduleDate').datepicker({ dateFormat : 'dd, MM, yy'});

var dateFormat = $('#scheduleDate').datepicker('option', 'dd, MM, yy');

$('#scheduleDate').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd, MM, yy');

var result = $('#scheduleDate').val();

alert('result: ' + result);
```

result: 20, April, 2012