# Store value from date picker on to a variable

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery date picker.

Code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

I have looked at other solutions but it did not solve my problem.([get selected value in datePicker and format it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266456/get-selected-value-in-datepicker-and-format-it)) I basically want to store the date selected from date picker to a variable so I can pass the variable on to a sql query. In my database the date is in the format of dd/mm/yyyy. Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks

what i tried

```
<script>
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd, mm, yy' });
  var datevariable = $("#datepicker").val();
  console.log(datevariable);  // i see no value
    </script>
```

Comment: The first answer in the question to which you link shows exactly how to store the value of the input in a variable... `dateVariable = $("input").val();`  Even the question itself shows how it's done.  Have you tried anything?  What didn't work?

Comment: Hey @David Thank you for answering. I tried that but it shows its undefined even though i have defined the variable.

Comment: Please update the question to show your attempt and indicate specifically how it's not working as expected.

Comment: hey david i have updated. Thanks

Comment: You're getting the value *immediately* when the page loads.  At that time the user hasn't actually entered anything yet.  You'll likely want to get the value at a later time, such as when the value in the input changes or when a button is clicked.