# How can I use a jQuery datepicker to display the date and auto update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to make the jQuery work with the rest of the js and display the date in descending order on a chart. This is the basis of what I have so far. Where it says "document.write(x);" I need it to display the date that is picked by the user.

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <style>
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="datepicker">
        <div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var x;
            $(function date() {
              $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                  onClose: function(dateText) {
                     var x = dateText;
                     alert("x = " + x);
                  }
                });
              $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', {dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'});
          });
            </script>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="price-chart">
    <div class="attr-col">
        <ul>
            <li>Service 1:</li>
            <li>Service 2:</li>
            <li>Service 3:</li>
            <li>Service 4:</li>
            <li>Service 5:</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="pt-table">
        <div class="pt-body">
            <ul class="pt-rows">
                <li class="title">
                <span><script type="text/javascript">
                document.write(x);
                </script></span>
```

Comment: Can you post some solutions you've tried that haven't worked?

Comment: Datepicker has a [`.getDate()` function](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) for exactly this purpose. *Off-topic:  don't embed `<script>` tags in content html*

Comment: `$('li.title').find('span').html(x);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  onClose: function(dateText){
     x = dateText;
     alert("x = " + x);
     $("li.title>span").eq(0).html(x);
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you know how I can added dates below that would be in descending order? Something like July 8, July 7, etc?

Comment: do you mean every time you update the date, to have a history list sorted by date? the is no simple way with jquery, but what I did once, was to save the date without separtor and modify the order into a data attribute, so the the date: 12/01/2014 will be rendered as data-date-int="20140112" so in this way you can sort comparing the new date every time you add by doing if first time .append(x) if greater .after(x); if smaller .before(x);

Comment: I meant that I to pick the date and then 6 days behind it would show up too. I thought I could do something like document.write(dateTime-1) etc. is there any equation like that i could do?

Comment: yes, you can first you have to get the date object from jquery datepicker like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919873/how-to-get-the-date-from-jquery-ui-datepicker and then follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime

Comment: I have this so far
inline `code in backticks`,
'var today = new Date();
            var yesterday = new Date();
            $(function date() {
             $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                onClose: function(dateText){
                   currentDate = dateText;
                   $("li.title>span").eq(0).html(currentDate);}
              });
              $('#datepicker').datepicker( "getDate" );
           $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', {dateFormat: 'M d'});
          });
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
                document.write(yesterday);'

Comment: here is my other question better worded and code is there. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891395/how-to-use-jquery-datepicker-to-show-multiple-dates-in-descending-order

Answer (score 0):

Your value of x in the span is not updating after you change it in your onClick function.  Give your span where you want the date to appear an id of "date" and then add the last line in the onClose function:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  onClose: function(dateText){
    x = dateText;
    alert("x = " + x);
    $("#date").html(x);
  }
});
```

This will automatically update every time you change the value of x.