# How to use jQuery Datepicker to show multiple dates in descending order

Tags: jquery, date, object

I just need to get the dates in descending order. Ex. User selects July 11, so July 11, July 10, July 9, etc.

```
var currentDate;
$(function date() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onClose: function(dateText){
            currentDate = dateText;
            var today = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' );
            $("li.title>span").eq(0).html(currentDate);
            $("li.title>span").eq(0).html(currentDate);
        }
    });

    $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', {dateFormat: 'M d'});
});
document.write(dateText);

<span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var yesterday = new Date();
        yesterday.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
        document.write(yesterday);
    </script>
</span>
```

Comment: So you're asking how to get the dates between the 1st of the month and the selected date?

Comment: I just want to select one date ex. July 20 and then the 6 days behind it should show up in a chart like July 19, July 18, July 17, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'M d',
    onClose: function(){
        var today = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' );
        writeDates(today);
    }
});

function writeDates(d){

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        var myDate = new Date(d);
        myDate.setDate(d.getDate() - i);
        var li =  $('<li>', {
            text: myDate
        });
        $('#result').append(li);    
    }    

}
```

Here's the action:
http://jsfiddle.net/LBeb2/2/

Comment: You should be able to play around with this and get the proper date formatting, and display.