# use date difference to output a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am creating a site, on which you can register a dog.
In the registration form you can enter your dog's birthdate using the jquery datepicker. This part works.
**The goal**
1) When a birthdate is picked by the user I would like to automatically calculate the difference between the entered date and today.
2) Use the difference between the dates to display the dog's age group in another form field.
 (puppy (< 6 months), young (<2 years), adult (<6 years) and so on..)
**My code**

```
    <!-- Datepicker -->
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
          dateFormat: "dd. MM yy",
          altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          altField: "#dog_pet_birthdate",
          maxDate: "0",

         <!-- my attempt on calculating the difference
         between the entered date and the current date -->
          onSelect: function () {
                var birthDate = $("#dog_pet_birthdate").datepicker("birthdate");
                var now = new Date();
                var days = (now - birthDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
                $("#dog_pet_age").val(days);
            }
          });
      });
    </script>

    <!-- the register form (the relevant parts)-->
    <label>Birthday:</label>
    <!-- date to be displayed -->
    <input type="text" name="birthdate" id="datepicker" placeholder="your dog's brithdate" readonly="readonly" required>
    <!-- date to be written to the database using the altField -->
    <input type="hidden" name="dog_pet_birthdate" id="dog_pet_birthdate">

    <!-- the input field, in which I would like to output the age group depending on the date difference -->        
    <label>Age group</label>
    <input type="text" name="dog_pet_age" placeholder="your dog's age" readonly="readonly" required>
```

I am really stuck, I did not even manage to calculate the difference between now and the entered date, therefore I did not even try the second part of my question. If somebody could help me out with both, I would be beyond thankful!

Comment: Try to convert `birthDate` string to date `var dtBirthDate = new Date(birthDate);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var birthDate` is not properly working.
To get a date, you need to use `getDate`, [see here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate).

You should do something like :

`var birthDate $("#datepicker").datepicker(' getDate ');`

[More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919873/how-to-get-the-date-from-jquery-ui-datepicker)

You can then use this difference to display what you want :

```
if(parseInt(your_string)<60){
$("#dog_pet_age").val("your value");
}
else if(parseInt(your_string)<120){
$("#dog_pet_age").val("another..");
}
else
{
$("#dog_pet_age").val("the rest!");}
```

Comment: Wow!! That works! It does give me back the difference in days. Thank you so much!! Is there any chance you could help me out with how to use this number to display a string?

Comment: Sure. :) You'll probably use a `if` and `parseInt` statement, such as :

`if(parseInt(your_string)<60){
$("#dog_pet_age").val("your value");
}
else if(parseInt(your_string)<120){
$("#dog_pet_age").val("another..");
}
else
{
$("#dog_pet_age").val("the rest!");}
`

I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var now = Date.now();

var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker(' getDate ');

var days = (now - date)/1000/60/60/24;

$('#example').val() = days;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Docteur already gave a working answer above. However, if you could help me out with displaying a string according to the number of days, I would be really really thankful!