# jQuery UI datepicker output in a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to create a field that displays the selected date on the jQueryUI datepicker. How do I do that?

Got the following code:

Javascript:

```
        $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            inline: true,
            onSelect: function () {
                $('#date').val(this.value)
            }
        });
    });
```

And the Html:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>

            <br>
            <p><input id = "date">
```

It's working now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the date from jQuery UI datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919873/how-to-get-the-date-from-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want. Do you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/06paz5ef/?

Comment: If that's what you needed, let me know and I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var currentDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker( "getDate" );
```

Change this line in your code.