# Bootstrap datetimepicker get the date and call the ajax call

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
$("#modal-new ").datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
});
```

how can i get the date from the text box and call the ajax file to pocess the data

I am trying this, but i am failed to get the date.

```
$( "#new_apt_date" ).change(function() {
          alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a similar question to this one:

[How to get the date from jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919873/how-to-get-the-date-from-jquery-ui-datepicker)

I've created the following JSFiddle which solves your problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/qnntwvk5/

```
$("#modal-new").datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
});

$("#modal-new").on("dp.change", function(e) {
    console.log( "Handler for .change() called." );
    console.log( e.date );
});
```

The format that comes back as `e.date` is in Moment.js, which you can format out however you want. For example:

```
e.date.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
```

You really need to include a working JSFiddle, to assist people in providing an answer.

Comment: I can make that work, but if I have more than one datetimepicker, I can't differentiate by selector, if I add :
    $("#modal-new").on("dp.change", ".anyotherselecter", function(e) {
it doesn't work... it seems the only way is to broadly get the event with dp-change and filter it by target, which kind of sucks.