# Trying to get number of weeks between two date in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden form like this

**HTML**

```
<h2> First Date</h2>
<input type="hidden" class="datepicker" id="startDate" value="29-10-2015" />

<h2> Second Date</h2>
<input type="hidden" class="datepicker" id="endDate" value="29-12-2015" />

<button type="button" id="test">Click It</button>
<p>Total Weeks</p>
```

**JAVAScript**

```
$("input").datepicker();

    $('#test').click(function () {
        var end = $('#endDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}).val();
        var start = $('#startDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}).val();

        var $weekDiff = Math.floor((end - start + 1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 7);

        alert('Total Weeks :'+$weekDiff);
    });
```

When I am printing the Dates in hidden input field from Database and it is in the format that I have pasted here

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jafaoej5/9/)

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: [How to get the date from jQuery UI datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919873/how-to-get-the-date-from-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 4):

Convert to ms and divide by ms per week.

```
// date1 = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate');
// date2 = $('#endDate').datepicker('getDate');

function nWeeks(date1, date2) {
    var WEEK = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

    var date1ms = date1.getTime();
    var date2ms = date2.getTime();

    var diff = Math.abs(date2ms - date1ms);

    return Math.floor(diff / WEEK);
}
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) is a reference about JS date objects.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```js
$("input").datepicker()

$('#test').on('click', () => {
  const end = $('#endDate').datepicker('getDate'),
    start = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate'),
    $weekDiff = Math.floor((end - start + 1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 7);

  $('#total').html($weekDiff)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<h2> First Date</h2>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="startDate" value="12/10/2015" />
<h2> Second Date</h2>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="endDate" value="12/29/2015" />
<button type="button" id="test">Click It</button>
<p>Total Weeks</p><span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: did you run my snippet? if you want i can put this into  a fiddle as well

Comment: bro but in this case it should show 8 weeks right if I am not wrong http://jsfiddle.net/fndxm9hm/1/ why is it still showing 0

Comment: Ok I found the issue.. the problem is the dates are like the 12-10-2015, should be 12/10/2015, see my updated Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert JS strings to integers in mathematical expressions, which will result in `NaN`.

So you need to first do `Date.parse( string )`.

With your fiddle it would be:

```
$("input").datepicker();

$('#test').click(function () {
    var end = $('#endDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}).val();
    var start = $('#startDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}).val();

    end = Date.parse( end );
    start = Date.parse( start );

    alert( [end, start] );

    var $weekDiff = Math.floor((end - start + 1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 7);

    alert('Total Weeks :'+$weekDiff);
});
```

With es6, and some shortening:

```
$("input").datepicker();

$('#test').click( () => {
    const [end, start] = ["#endDate", "startDate"]
        .map( e => Date.parse( e.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}).val() ) );

    const diff = Math.floor((end - start + 1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 7);
    console.log('Total Weeks :' + diff);
});
```

Comment: can you show me a fiddle of this because when I try to use it it still alert's NaN

Comment: Which one, the es6 or the other? Worked for me when I selected 2 dates from the 2 inputs using the normal JS. I didn't test the es6 one but it is just a shortening. Note: before you have entered 2 dates it won't work.

Comment: The fiddle you posted works fine for me **after** selecting 2 dates. It shows NaN before as it is supposed to do.

Comment: that is the problem I am getting those two values from a php variable and this input box is hidden and the dates are 29-10-2015 and 29-12-2015 but if i put this dates static in the html the Js returns NaN   http://jsfiddle.net/jafaoej5/17/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
$("input").datepicker();

$('#test').click(function () {
    var end = $('#endDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}).val();
    var start = $('#startDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}).val();

    var $weekDiff = Math.floor((end - start + 1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 7);

    alert(daydiff(parseDate(start), parseDate(end)));
});



function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/')
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24) / 7);
}
```

Updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jafaoej5/25/)

Comment: No need to roll your own parseDate... there's already an implementation in the standard: `Date.parse(...)`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: @Centril There is already a method implemented by `datepicker` ;)

Comment: @carstenLovboAndersen I tried checking your Fiddle but it still results into NaN

Comment: @Vikram If you just click the button without taking something it returns nah, but if select something it do work

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen actually I am getting the dates from PHP variable and its in mm/dd/yyyy formate and I am putting them in the hidden input type .

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
$('#test').click(function () {
    var end = $('#endDate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}).val();
    var start = $('#startDate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}).val();
    var aDate1 = end.split('-');
    var aDate2 = start.split('-');
    end = Date.UTC(aDate1[2], aDate1[1] - 1, aDate1[0]);
    start = Date.UTC(aDate2[2], aDate2[1] - 1, aDate2[0]);
    alert(Math.floor((end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
});
```