# how to get the date value from an jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have been trying for the last couple of hours to get the date from a UI datepicker

I used

```
$( your_datepicker_id ).datepicker( "getDate" )
```

from 
  "[How to get the date from jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919873/how-to-get-the-date-from-jquery-ui-datepicker)"

but debug shows it returns a object. I also replaced "getDate" with "val". I googled many sites and they all give the same answer.

All I want is the date.

Comment: Can you put together a fiddle?

Comment: I have tried but I don't know where to start. I can't even get jquery loaded.

Comment: *" debug shows it returns a object."* - that should be a JavaScript date object. It contains all the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(your_datepicker_id).val()
```

Comment: I tried that but although the datepicker box contains a date I get "undefined" in the debugger. I am using Firefox 46.0.1 and have restarted it twice. I find dates difficult in jscript.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure date is selected before you try to get it. Please follow this snippet which explains how to retrieve date via "val()" and "getdate" method.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

    $("#btnD").click(function(){
    var currentDate = $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
alert(currentDate);
    });

  $("#btnI").click(function(){
    var currentDate = $( "#datepicker" ).val();
   alert(currentDate);
    });
});

  </script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<button id="btnD">Get Date</button>
<button id="btnI">Get Input value</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but when I click on the date field it does not display any date box for me to pick from. I get "jQuery not defined" in the Console log. If I type in a date neither buttons display anything.

Comment: Make sure you are loading jquery and jquery ui library. Or could you please share a fiddle?