# How to get day of the week using date with dd-mm-yy format

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have set an input to be a date picker using `datepicker()` on document ready and I have set the format to be `dd-mm-yy`.

When the input is changed I get the value of the input with `Date()`.

My issue is that `Date()` is expecting a format of `mm-dd-yy` so when I use `getDay()` test to see which day it is, it returns the wrong value.

How can I make this code work using the `dd-mm-yy` format?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if( $('#booking_form').length ){
        $('#date input')
            .prop('readonly', true)
            .datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
    }

    $('#date input').change(function(){
        date_function();
    });

    function date_function(){
        //getting the date  
        var date = new Date( $('#date input').val() );


        if( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 1 ){
            $('#custom_error').show();
        } else {
            $('#custom_error').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't use UK date formats in Date object. They have to be in US format. See the duplicate ways to convert them

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: The datepicker plugin should provide a method to get/set the date directly, not by using the input's value, eg `var date = $("#date input").datepicker("getDate")`

Comment: Depends on your datepicker, but a better duplicate may be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4919890/2181514

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I got my answer from the first link. Thanks